# How to suppress "Object is possibly 'undefined'" in nested objects in redux

Tags: typescript, redux

Consider we have the interface for our redux state as follows:

```js
interface State {
    designs: {
        [key: number]: {
            textboxes?: {
                [key: number]: { override: boolean};
            }
        };
    };
}
```

In one of our reducer cases we have:

```js
case 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE': {
    const { designId, textboxId } = action.meta;
    draft.designs[designId].textboxes[textboxId].override = true;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

    break;
}
```

How do I suppress this typescript error?
I've used these with no luck:

1. `draft.designs[designId] && draft.designs[designId].textboxes[textboxId].override = true;`
2. `draft.designs?.[designId].textboxes?.[textboxId].override = true;`

Comment: Assert that it is not undefined with `!`: `draft.designs[designId]!.textboxes...`

Comment: I have `Forbidden non-null assertion` turned on. Can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's legitimate to do

```
const design = draft.designs[designId]
if (design) {
    const textbox = design.textboxes[textboxId];
    if (textbox) {
        textbox.override = true;
    }
}
```

But of course that's neither pretty nor concise. https://docs-lodash.com/v4/property-path/ Might help to do it better if you're willing to add some library for support.

One-line solution with optional chaining operator (`?`):

```
(drafts.designs[designId]?.textboxes[textboxId] || {}).override = true;
```

Comment: Yeah although this fixes the problem but it's not the most elegant solution as you also stated. And also adding Lodash is not an option. I'm thinking maybe there would be another solution?

Comment: @MohsenTaleb I added another solution to the answer. It fits in one line but is a bit obscure.